# Get message from SMS content URI where message is not delivered

Tags: android, sms, uri, smsmanager

I am developing a **system application** in which I have to send a message from device programmatically and delete the message after sending.Everything working properly except below point

**If the message sent successfully then I am able to find it from SMS content URI but if the message failures then I am not getting it from Content URI.I am using below code for deleting message**

```
 public void deleteTheMessage(Context context, String value) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor c = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    try {

        if (c != null) {
            Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", "  count : " + c.getCount());
        } else {
            Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", " c null: ");
        }
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            try {
                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String address = c.getString(2);
                        String id = c.getString(0);
                        long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                        Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", " address: " + address + " body: " + "" + " threadId: " + threadId + " id: " + id);
                        try {
                            if (address.contains(value)) {
                                int deltedrowcount = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(uri, "thread_id = " + threadId, null);
                                if (deltedrowcount != 0) {
                                    Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", " SMS has Deleted successfully " + deltedrowcount);
                                }
                                Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", " body  " + address);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", "SmsWriteOpUtil Exception in deleting SMS  " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", "c.moveToNext() Exception in deleting SMS" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("deleteTheMessage-->", " try Exception in deleting SMS: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

**I want to delete message address by 11345 Please see below screenshot.**

[image]

Comment: Which Android version are you testing on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am developing for Android 8.1, but I have also tested in 6.0 and it's not working

Comment: Is your app set as the default messaging app?

Comment: Yes and it will be a system app

Comment: Hmm. What results do you get if you query for just that number? That is, `query(uri, null, "address=?", new String[] { "11345" }, null)`.

Comment: getting **c.getCount()** is 0

Comment: Are you really, _really_ sure you're set as the default? Can you successfully delete messages? If you use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString()` with your original query, can you see that failed message in there anywhere? Are you testing on actual devices, or emulators?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163486/discussion-between-android-dev-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the solution to delete the **undelivered** message using below code.

```
        long threadId = Telephony.Threads.getOrCreateThreadId(context, phoneNumber);
        LogMgr.i("deleteByThreadID-->" + "  threadId : " + threadId);
        int threadIdDeletedCount = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms"), "thread_id =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(threadId)});
        LogMgr.i("deleteByThreadID: --> threadIdDeletedCount " + threadIdDeletedCount);
```

**phoneNumber** this the number on which message was sent.

Comment: Nice workaround. I still wonder, though, why you weren't able to get those messages in a regular query.